# Is this a sensible setup for interviews?

Tags: audio, interview

I'm buying equipment for a series of sit-down interviews involving two people which will be published online - our company's first go at producing these in-house.

We already have a few decent camcorders and tripods, but the sound quality from our current mic inputs into the camcorders is pretty poor. So I have hatched the following plan to improve sound quality in potentially crowded environments:

**Audio recorder (Zoom H4n Pro/UK Handy Recorder, £185) with two Movo LV4-C lavalier mics connected by XLR into it.**

Video would be recorded as is (we are happy with the video quality).

Sync with a clap, mash together in post-production.

We're new to all this, so if someone with expertise could vouch for the sensibleness of this plan, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Straight up, yes, I'd say this is a sensible setup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know those Movo mics at all, but I see nothing at all wrong with the rest of the plan.

Sync to clap is a pretty standard way of doing it. You can line it up by sight in your editing suite afterwards, no issues. You can even shuffle each side for phase, should you need to.
I've never personally used the H4n Pro, but I know a lot of people who do & are very happy with it.

Personally, I'd go for something 'better' than 50 quid mics I'd never heard of, but I've been spoiled by years of being the proud owner of some DPA 4060s, which you'd have to go a very long way to beat. They would unfortunately stretch your budget by another 700 quid, for a pair.

Maybe rent some mics first & try before you buy.